# Creating URL's in for loop by picking values from list in Python

Tags: python

In order to create get-requests I create a Python script. In order to create the URL's for this request I have made the following code:

```py
today = str(datetime.date.today())
start = str(datetime.date.today()- datetime.timedelta (days=30))

report = ["Shifts",
          "ShiftStops",
          "ShiftStopDetailsByProcessDate",
          "TimeRegistrations",
          "ShiftsByProcessDate",
          "ShiftStopsByProcessDate",
          ]

for x in report:
    url_data = "https://URL"+ report + "?from=" + start + "&until=" + today
    data = requests.get(url_data, headers = {'Host': 'services.URL.com', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + acces_token})
```

But the error I get is:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

What can I do to solve this and create 6 unique url's?

p.s. I have added the word URL to the URL's in order to anonymize my post.

Comment: `"https://URL"+ report ` it should be `"https://URL"+ x` and also fix the indentation

Comment: @deadshot thank you for your reply! the indentation was last when copying to this forum. I have restored the indentation. And the mentioned probem is indeed solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you're going wrong is in the following line:

`url_data = "https://URL"+ report + "?from=" + start + "&until=" + today`

Specifically, you use `report` which is the entire list. What you'll want to do is use `x` instead, i.e. the string *in* the list.

Also you'll want to indent the next line, so altogether it should read:

```
for x in report:
    url_data = "https://URL"+ x + "?from=" + start + "&until=" + today
    data = requests.get(url_data, headers = {'Host': 'services.URL.com', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + acces_token})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the answer. The list of url's is created by replacing `report` by `x` while create the url_data.

```py
url_data = "https://URL"+ x + "?from=" + start + "&until=" + today
```